# Is there a way to access VSCode workspace from desktop shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I have a very basic setup such as a Raspberry Pi set up as a local web development server which I access with SSH keys (passphrase is configured automatically with SSH Agent service) and this is where I store my project. Now I have a certain Workspace there with some custom configurations and other settings.

I have tried to search in Google to quick access it, but found no way so far. In short, I would like to access this workspace with a desktop shortcut on the windows, which will open this workspace for me in VS Code, so I do not need to open VS Code and access this workspace manually.

Is there a way to access VSCode workspace from desktop shortcut?

Any help is very welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`--folder-uri` argument](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_connect-to-a-remote-host-from-the-terminal) to `code` to open an SSH workspace folder (i.e. a [single-folder workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_singlefolder-workspaces)):

```bash
--folder-uri vscode-remote://ssh-remote+<your-hostname><your-folder>
```

E.g. if the hostname of your Raspberry Pi is `rpi` and your workspace is located in `/home/myuser/workspace`, open VS Code as follows:

```bash
code --folder-uri vscode-remote://ssh-remote+rpi/home/myuser/workspace
```

If you want to open a [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces#_multiroot-workspaces), you need to include the workspace file at the end of the path as follows:

```bash
code --folder-uri vscode-remote://ssh-remote+rpi/home/myuser/workspace-folder/workspace-file-name.code-workspace
```

If `code` is in your `PATH`, using this line as target for your desktop shortcut should do the trick.

Alternatively, to have the VS Code icon on your shortcut, use the complete path to your `code.exe`, e.g.:

```
"C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --folder-uri vscode-remote://ssh-remote+rpi/home/myuser/workspace
```